# Get text value from custom ComboBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, combobox, multibinding

I have a ComboBox defined as below:

```
<ComboBox Width="200" Height="30" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ExistingSpeciesComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SpeciesColorCollection}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Brush}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Height="15" Width="30"/>
                <w:WTextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              Foreground="{StaticResource SmallControlForegroundBrush}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

SpeciesColorCollection is an ObservableCollection of type ColorObject

```
Public Class ColorObject
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Brush As Brush
End Class
```

The ComboBox displays the items from the collection correctly but my problem is when I try to get the selected text from the ComboBox in a MultiBinding, I receive ColorObject instead of the name. How do I go about getting the value of the "Name" from within the WTextBlock of the ComboBox? The binding that I am using for my command is below. The converter is only returning strings.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mySpeciesSetupConverter}">
    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
        <Binding ElementName="NewSpeciesName" Path="Text" />
        <Binding ElementName="ExistingSpeciesComboBox" Path="Text" />
    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
 </MultiBinding>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mySpeciesSetupConverter}">
    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
        <Binding ElementName="NewSpeciesName" Path="Text" />
        <Binding ElementName="ExistingSpeciesComboBox" Path="SelectedItem.Name" />
    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I knew it had to be something simple but I just couldn't put my finger on it!

Comment: @dkirkdrei  that's great , so why don't you accept the answer ;)

Comment: Answer accepted! I was trying but it made me wait 7 minutes??